# LaravelサイトのURL変更で、なぜかフォルダ名が二重になってしまう

Tags: php, laravel

次のような環境で作業をしています。
laravel10 + vue3 + inertia + vite + typescript + tailwindcss

xserverを利用しています。各状況は次のとおりです。

> Laravelフォルダは ~/source/my_project/
> 公開フォルダは ~/example.com/public/
> 公開URLは　https://example.com/

/soruce/my_project/public と ~/example.com/public/　にシンボリックを貼りました。

無事に https://example.com/ にて表示されるようになりました。
すべてのリンクの動作も問題が有りません。

#### フォルダを１つ下げると問題発生

運用において、１つフォルダを下げてLaravelを表示しようとしました。
新たな状況は次のとおりになります。toolというフォルダ配下にしました。

> Laravelフォルダは ~/source/my_project/　※変更なし
> 公開フォルドは ~/example.com/public/tool/
> 公開URLは　https://example.com/tool/

シンボリックリンクも  ~/example.com/public/tool/ から貼り直しています。
.env の APP_URL も https://example.com/tool に変更

念のためキャッシュもすべて削除

```
php artisan config:clear
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan route:clear
```

実際にアクセスしてみると、次のような挙動が発生します。
https://example.com/tool/ →　https://example.com/tool/tool　とURL表示
コンテンツ部分は問題なく表示されています。URL部分だけ何故か tool が二重になります。

内部のリンクはすべて https://example.com/tool/xxxxxx のようになっています。
クリックするとちゃんと表示されます。
しかし、URL部分は https://example.com/tool/tool/xxxxxx になります。

URLの表示だけがオカシイ状況です。

そのため、https://example.com/tool/tool に直接アクセスすると 404 エラー
リンクから移動後、https://example.com/tool/tool/xxxxxx でリロードすると 404 エラー

という不思議な状況にあります。

.htaccess は全くいじっていません。
最初の https://example.com/.htaccess を削除しましたが状況変わらずです。

このような状況が発生する原因は何が考えられるでしょうか？
よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

パッチを当てることで対応しました。

### composer 管理ファイル

1. composer-patches をインストール
   `composer require cweagans/composer-patches`
2. 問い合わせには y

   ```php
   Do you trust "cweagans/composer-patches" to execute code and wish to enable it now?
    (writes "allow-plugins" to composer.json) [y,n,d,?]

   cweagans/composer-patches」のコード実行を信頼し、今すぐ有効化したいですか？
   (composer.jsonにallow-pluginsを書き込む) [y,n,d,?]。
   ```
3. rootに`patches_composer` をフォルダを作成する ※package.json用の patchesフォルダと分ける
4. 対象ファイルのバックアップを作成する cp コピー元 コピー先

   `cp vendor/inertiajs/inertia-laravel/src/Response.php vendor/inertiajs/inertia-laravel/src/Response.php.orig`
5. 対象ファイルを編集する
6. 動作確認
7. 差分ファイルを作る

   `diff -u 変更前ファイル名 変更後ファイル名 patches_composer/差分記録ファイル名`

   `diff -u vendor/inertiajs/inertia-laravel/src/Response.php.orig vendor/inertiajs/inertia-laravel/src/Response.php > patches_composer/inertia-laravel-response.patch`
8. パッチファイルの修正

   patches_composer/inertia-laravel-response.patch

   ※composer.jsonでライブラリを指定するが、その「フォルダ」から相対指定

   ```php
   --- vendor/inertiajs/inertia-laravel/src/Response.php.orig  2023-05-26 07:43:20.246192609 +0900
   +++ vendor/inertiajs/inertia-laravel/src/Response.php   2023-05-26 07:41:02.059394179 +0900
   ↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓ 先頭行がパッチ対象ファイル
   --- src/Response.php    2023-05-26 07:43:20.246192609 +0900
   +++ src/Response.php    2023-05-26 07:41:02.059394179 +0900
   @@ -99,7 +99,7 @@
            $page = [
                'component' => $this->component,
                'props' => $props,
   -            'url' => $request->getBaseUrl().$request->getRequestUri(),
   +            'url' => $request->getRequestUri(),
                'version' => $this->version,
            ];
   ```
9. **`composer.json`** ファイルにパッチの情報を追加

   ```php
   {
       "require": {
           "php": "^7.3",
           // 他のパッケージ
       },
       "extra": {
           "patches": {
               "inertiajs/inertia-laravel": {
                   "修正の説明": "patches_composer/inertia-laravel-response.patch"
               }
           }
       },
       // その他のセクション
   }
   ```

composer update -vvv でデバッグモードになる

composer install でパッチの実行　※updateでは実行されない

> ⚠️ 注：「can't find file to patch at input line 3」というメッセージは正常であり、パッチのエラーではない
> https://maxcluster.de/en/knowledge-base/managedcenter/fasteristableexists

### package.json 管理ファイル

1. patch-packageをインストール

   `npm install --save-dev patch-package`
2. プログラムの修正 対象ファイルを修正する
3. パッチファイルを作成

   `npx patch-package @inertiajs/vue3`
4. **`patches`** ディレクトリに **`@inertiajs+vue3+1.0.0.patch`** というファイルが作られる
5. `package.json` ファイルを開き、`scripts` セクションに `postinstall` スクリプトを追加

   ```php
   "scripts": {
     "postinstall": "patch-package"
   }
   ```
6. 以上で、`npm install, npm update` が実行されてアップデートされたとしても、パッチの状態に更に上書きをしてくれる
7. 公式ファイルが更新されてパッチが不要になったら、
   **`patches`** ディレクトリの **`@inertiajs+vue3+1.0.0.patch`** を削除すればOK

Answer (score 0):

こちらで同じ現象と、その解決方法がありました。

[root directory is displayed twice in URL on load and reload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71943581/root-directory-is-displayed-twice-in-url-on-load-and-reload)

vendor/inertiajs/src/Response.php の toResponse() メソッドを書き換えると…
もっとも、venderフォルダ内のファイルの変更は上書きリスクがあるので、悩ましい。